# Proving that Zariski Topology is actually a topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I am reading from class notes given by a senior and I was unable to prove this assertion. I think I need help in this:

> Define $V_K(A)= ${$a\in K^n |F(a)=0 $ for all $F\in  A$}, A is an ideal in a finite type K-algebra A' Prove that this is actually a topology called zariski topology.

Attempt: I have proved all the assertions except of finite union is also in topology.

It is sufficient to prove that for $V_L (A) \cup V_L(B) =V_L(A \cap B)$. In this I have proved that $V_L (A\cap B) \subseteq V_L(A)\cup V_L(B)$ but unable to prove the converse.

So, can you please help with that?

Comment: Unclear question: $A$ ranges over what?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma A is an ideal in a finite type K-algebra A'

Comment: An ideal where?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Did you had a look at my comment above?

Comment: I don't know what a finite type $K$-algebra $A'$ has to do with anything. Itn't $A$ just some set of $f \in K[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ so that $f(a) \in K$ for $a \in K^n$?

Comment: Does [this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3000868/4280) help?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Will have a look soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** it's easier to show
$$V(I) \cup V(J) = V(IJ) = V(I \cap J).$$

---

**Edit:** You've noted that you've shown $V(I \cap J) \subseteq V(I) \cup V(J)$. As we always have that $IJ \subseteq I \cap J \subseteq I,J$, it follows that (as $V(\cdot)$ is inclusion-reversing)
$$V(I),V(J) \subseteq V(I\cap J) \subseteq V(IJ)$$
hence
$$V(I) \cup V(J) \subseteq V(I \cap J) \subseteq V(IJ).$$
So with this, you are actually finished. The other method I alluded to above is showing that
$$V(I ) \cup V(J) \subseteq V(I \cap J) \subseteq V(IJ) \subseteq V(I) \cup V(J).$$
Which of course proves the hinted statement. The first two inclusions in the above line follow from the argument above, as for the last inclusion, take $p \in V(IJ)$, and assume without loss of generality that $f \not \in V(I)$. Then for all $g \in V(J)$, we have
$$(fg)(p) = f(p)g(p) = 0,$$
and as $K$ is a field hence an integral domain, and $f(p) \neq 0$ since $f \not \in V(I)$, we must have that $g(p) = 0$, so $p \in V(J)$. This proves this hint.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your hint?

Comment: @Jimmy See my edit above.